# Restoring Mac damaged my tex files

Tags: texmaker, texshop

I had to restore my Mac, and now that I downloaded Texmaker, the app doesn't recognize any of my files and I'm getting something similar to this ������������

Is there a solution for this

Comment: It's possible that your files are fine and that your editor opened the files with the wrong encoding. You might consider posting this in a more technical forum, like Stack Overflow, or the Mac Stack Exchange site, because here it's the LaTeX forum and your problem very likely has nothing to do with using LaTeX.

Comment: Have you tried opening the files in any other text editor? Or just `cat`ting them in th terminal to see what the contents look like there? What does it show for the encoding in the bottom right of texmaker? Does "Toos > Convert to Unicode" (trying different input encodings) do anything?